# How to use distinct when you select multiple column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, distinct, common-table-expression

I have use simple inner join statement and getting result into CTE table. I want to select distinct 'ServiceId' from CTE. I have following query

```
  SELECT DISTINCT(ServicesId), ServiceNo, ServiceDate, DealerCode FROM CTE_Temp
```

Suppose there are duplicate entries of ServiceId in CTE then I want to select first entry only and ignore rest of them.

Comment: Define "first" - tables and views don't have any inherent order. If you have a particular order in mind (based on some column(s)), you need to tell us (and SQL Server) what order you want to use.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function on a column, it works on the whole selected rows!!! "select distinct (col1), col2" eq "select distinct col1, col2" eq "select distinct col1, (col2)"!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` for this. Just replace the column in the `ORDER BY` to define what's first.

```
;WITH AnotherCTE AS(
    SELECT 
        ServicesId, ServiceNo, ServiceDate, DealerCode,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ServicesID ORDER BY ServiceDate DESC)
    FROM CTE_Temp
)
SELECT 
    ServicesId, ServiceNo, ServiceDate, DealerCode
FROM AnotherCTE
WHERE RN = 1
```